Perito vs Perrito
If I wanted to say "I need an expert", would this be accurate?

Necesito un perito.  

I'm guessing, that a better way to say it would be 

Necesito un experto.

I find it odd that the word "perito" is so very similar (to me as an English speaker), to the word "perrito" which is a puppy or small dog.  Especially if I actually did mean to say that I needed a puppy - but I didn't "twirl" my r's :), hence it might sound like I was saying "perito" instead of "perrito".

No, perito en x is very much used. You can look this stuff up in the RAE.

@Lambie I totally disagree. Perito is not used. You can see for yourself checking the ngram for "perito en, experto en"

It's used lot in legal contexts and courts like this https://sercofi2.webnode.es/peritaje-contable/ El perito contable es un especialista que se encargará de esclarecer hechos contables que se encentren en una controversia judicial.

@RubioRic I completely disagree with you, because "perito" is used a lot, and it is also often referred to as "peritajes" or "peritar tal o cual cual cosa".

@Aradnix You can disagree all you want. The Ngram is there. I mean that is not used as synonym of "expert", in the context that OP asked

@Aradnix You can check my answer below  for additional info

As you can see in the DRAE, perito is an adjective. It can be used as a noun but then it changes a bit the meaning. It's not considered an expert in general but

A "Ingeniero Técnico Industrial" - deprecated, at least in Spain - because that kind of grade is no longer available in our universities. In the recent past perito was associated to that "técnico" part, meaning that you get that grade after coursing three years, in opposition of being Ingeniero Industrial after five years.

As mentioned by tac, the one that executes the action of peritar (verb). An expert can peritar a lot of things in many contexts but the most common meaning is person in charge of evaluating the damages for the insurance companies. This meaning is the one used in courts of justice also.


You can use perito for a generic expert but as pure adjective along with a sustantive:

Necesito alguien perito en Inteligencia Artificial

But you don't find that kind of sentence in daily conversations, it's not colloquial. You can find it in literature.
So I would recommend to use just experto in your context.
Talking about similar sounding words, what you have with perito and perrito, it's more or less what most of us Spanish native speakers have with beach-bitch or ship-sheep. ;-P
You can verify my statements checking this Ngram ("perito en" vs "experto en")

And last but not least, just a fun fact: perita (always in feminine) is slang for good or nice here in my home town, Málaga (Spain)

[EN] He's a nice guy
[ES - Malagueño] Es un tío perita
[EN] He's a very nice guy
[ES - Malagueño] Es un tío to' perita


We really do say noun. And your use of grade is not right.

@Lambie 1. Fixed. 2. What's the proper name?

In my opinion, using Ngram here is not of much value and even a little misleading. It is true that the word "experto" is much more used as a general term but the word "perito" has very specific meanings in certain contexts. For example, in Mexico "perito" is also used to convey the meaning that such a person has a certification to give an opinion about a specific matter.

@Krauss I tried to cover that case showing the second meaning associated to "perito", the one that executes the action of peritar. The key is what you have mentioned: very specific vs generic. Without additional context from the OP, I assumed that the question was about a generic expert.

Yes, I agree that as a generic term, "experto" is a best choice.

Por un lado, debo decir que recomiendo traducir expert simplemente como ‘eminencia’, ‘profesional’ o ‘experto’. El perito es el experto en peritaje, o sea es un hipónimo de experto, un tipo de experto entre todos los que hay. Así que no: aunque aparece en el DRAE como simplemente ‘experto’ y después como ‘ingeniero’ eso es un yerro muy grosero; muy mal ahí, sólo vas a conseguir generar más confusión en la conversación. En todo caso, debieron aclarar en dónde se le dice ‘perito’ a cualquier experto porque ni de cerca esas acepciones son universales.
Por otro lado, en cuanto a lo de la erre, así es el español. Si bien es cierto que es más tolerante en cuanto a la pronunciación que el inglés (por ejemplo, más laxo con la pronunciación de la a o de la i), tampoco es cierto que se tolera cualquier tipo de fonema como alófono y saber diferenciar entre la ‘r’ y la ‘rr’ es fundamental para cualquiera (ej: para disinguir entre ‘quería’ y ‘querría’, ambas conjugaciones de ‘querer’).
